# angularjs evaluating expression recommendation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a ng-repeat where there is a css class in the div. I need to flip it's value based on the one of the property of the current record.

What is the recommended way here.

write an expression like

or can i write a method in the ctrl and invoke here?

i am new to it so please advise. writing expression seems cluttering html a lot.

Comment: you can use ng-class for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use a directive that will control what you need ( directive that will work based on a value from html ) or use ng-class if is not something very complicated you want to do with